Alternatives for a Quartz-crystal microbalance holder
I am building a kind of frequency analyzer as a side project and don't have the money to buy a high-end QCM sensor holder (image below).
I'm not really even sure how to connect these sensors to my circuit and would like to hear suggestions on how I could find or build a holder for them.


From what I have been able to find it looks like one terminal is the perimeter track on the back of the sensor and the other contact is the edge of the face of the sensor.
]
https://www.filtech.com/products/product-category/crystals-hardware-monitors-and-controllers/

Do you know if there is a way i can build my own holder? How complicated would the process be?

you're going to need a lathe and probably glass blowing equipment to make the insulator. will probably take several days, depending on skill level.

These crystals are designed to measure the mass of a thin film deposited on the front surface. The holder is designed to expose the front surface, provide electrical contact, and allow the crystal to vibrate in the desired mode with minimum mechanical loss. In other words, designed by someone who understands the ultrasonic physics.
Fabrication should not be difficult if you have access to a good machine shop.
